# How to determine the current iPhone OS version at runtime and compare version strings?

Tags: iphone

How can you determine and compare (>, <, etc.) the current OS version of the iPhone that the app is running on? There is a certain bug in 3.0 but not in 3.1+ so I'd like to be able to skip out a bit of code if the current OS version is not >= 3.1.

This needs to be at runtime not compile time!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the bug?

Comment: It is a core data bug that causes a crash when both `setPropertiesToFetch:` and `setFetchBatchSize:` are used on an `NSFetchRequest`. This is only an issue in 3.0 as it was resolved by 3.1. Here's a link to the discussion: https://devforums.apple.com/message/101589#101589

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you mean determine the version of the OS? The SDK is fixed at build time, but the OS may change.  To get the OS version, use [UIDevice currentDevice]. systemVersion. To get the SDK version, I think you can use __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED.

Comment: Ah okay, yes the current OS version! As `systemVersion` returns a string (@"1.2", @"3.1.2"), how can this be compared and perform comparisons like < or >?

Comment: -[NSString intValue] or -[NSString floatValue]

Comment: Not able to test that at the moment, but how will `floatValue` handle a value such as 3.2.1? As it's not a valid floating point number?

Comment: If you need more than just the point-release, you may need to parse the string using, for example, -[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:].

Comment: Thanks! I used the `systemVersion` in conjunction with a slightly modified version of this function for comparisons: http://snipplr.com/view/2771/compare-two-version-strings/

Comment: See this snipped for a great implementation of Runtime iOS Version Checking: http://forr.st/~mOO

Answer (score 22):

You can for instance do something like this:

```
NSString *reqSysVer = @"3.1";
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
 {
    //Do some clever stuff
 }
```

Comment: This has a deficiency (bug?) - if reqSysVer is 4.2 and the current version is 4.1, then the test succeeds and you do clever stuff. The problem is that that method just tests the first number (I wrote some tests to determine that.) See my suggestion as the next comment.

Answer (score 2):

A more reliable way is to do something like this:

```
static inline NSComparisonResult compareCurVersionTo(int major, int minor, int point)
{
    NSUInteger testVers = major*10000 + minor*100 + point;
    NSUInteger curSysNum = 0;
    NSUInteger multi = 10000;
    for(NSString *n in [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."]) {
        curSysNum += [n integerValue] * multi;
        multi /= 100;
    }
    if(curSysNum < testVers) return NSOrderedAscending;
    if(curSysNum > testVers) return NSOrderedDescending;
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

This handles the "Leopard" bug where the minor releases were more than "9".

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer. Please see the following snippet which provides the best way to do this check: http://forr.st/~mOO It's hidden in the comments under the accepted answer!