# How to detect an iPhone app is running on iPhone 4 device or not?

Tags: iphone

I try to update an iPhone application to support the larger screen resolution on iPhone 4. How to detect if my app is running on iPhone 4 or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964776/determine-current-iphone-os-version-at-runtime-and-compare-version-strings

Comment: As I understand it, this is not the same question. He is not asking the OS version but the device version (e.g. iPhone 3G, or iPhone 4). This cannot be queried in the UIDevice class currenty. The SDK for iOS 4 might have a solution, but this would be still under NDA.

Comment: Can you instead make your app detect the screen size by checking the window/root view frame size?

Answer (score 0):

i can trace my iPhone 3GS through this code

```
struct utsname systemInfo;
uname(&systemInfo);                                                          
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.version
                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

i hope it will work for iPhone 4

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this method

```
-(NSString *) getDeviceType {
    return [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
}
```

Or just get it like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [UIDevice currentDevice].model);
```

To check if a device is retina capable do the following:

```
BOOL result;
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) result = TRUE; else result = FALSE;
```