# UITableView.backgroundColor in SDK 4.0

Tags: iphone, uitableview, backwards-compatibility, ios4

I have an app that has a custom background for a `UITableView`. Up to the SDK 3.1.3 this was done by setting the table's `backgroundColor` property to `[UIColor clearColor]` and placing the table on top of another view (a `UIImageView' for example). SDK 3.2 added the`backgroundView`property, and the same effect could be achieved by setting it to`nil`.

SDK 4.0 removed all traces of SDK 3.1.x libs, so it is impossible to compile a 4.0-compatible version that still works on 3.1.x devices.

If I create in SDK 3.2 an ad-hoc version and install it via iTunes on a 4.0 device,  everything is fine, the app works as expected and the world is happy. If I compile it on the SDK 4.0 it does not, even if I set the target to 3.0 and call `setBackgroundColor:` (so the compiler doesn't complain about a non-existant symbol).

So, is there any solution for this? I basically want to:
- compile with the SDK 4.0 (so I can test the app with a 4.0 device)
- make it work on 3.x devices
- use 3.1.x symbols, deprecated on 4.0, since the installed base is still huge

Comment: You may want to just do a version check when you are drawing your table and use the appropriate code there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964776/determine-current-iphone-os-version-at-runtime-and-compare-version-strings and turn off warnings if they get annoying: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622017/suppressing-deprecated-warnings-in-xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just weak-link UIKit.framework as stated in this question: [Recommended way to support backward/forward compatibility in iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954342/recommended-way-to-support-backward-forward-compatibility-in-iphone-app) and conditionally call the appropriate method with `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`